# variable resets upon frame

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a layer named GlobalActions Layer that is on the main timeline, that holds the variable called EnergyNumber.

On frame 2, but same scene, I have a button that subtracts 10 from the variable that's on the GlobalAction.

Finally, I have a button that returns you to frame 1.

I click that button that sends me back to frame 1, and the EnergyNumber would reset back to 100. How can I fix this?

Comment: Basically, I set a variable to 100, and a button is supposed to take away 10 each time it is clicked. However, the variable always resets itself back to 100 once I leave the frame the button is on.

Comment: HTML5, WebOS, ActionScript, PHP, Excel, iOS, Android?

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't specify. Actionscript 3

Answer (score 1):

Your variable will get redefined when you return to frame 1.

Solution:

1. Define your variable on frame one.
2. Never return to frame 1 - use frame 2 to hold whatever content you currently use for frame 1.
3. Move the content of frame 2 to frame 3.
4. Only alternate between frames 2 and 3.

Comment: You are a real lifesaver Marty! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to return to frame #1 without resetting the variable in the process.  Here's how:

```
var myVar;
if (myVar == undefined) myVar = true;
```

If you set "myVar" to "false" on another frame and then return, your code will see "false", since it's now a defined variable.